# Filtering an MVC SelectList from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

How would I filter a SelectList being populated from the database?  In this example, I only want white bunnies (Color is the property on the bunnies object) to show up in the list.   I have tried to add a where on the end of the Select but I only can see Id and Name as conditions I can filter on.

```
var bunnies = db.Bunnies.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                                    {
                                                        Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                                                        Text = x.Name,

                                                    }
                                                    );
        return new SelectList(bunnies , "Value", "Text");
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
var bunnies = db.Bunnies.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                                    {
                                                        Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                                                        Text = x.Name,

                                                    }
                                                    ).Where(p => p.Color == "white");
        return new SelectList(bunnies , "Value", "Text");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike in SQL, in LINQ the `Where` clause tends to come *before* the `Select` clause (unless you want to filter only on those fields that you've projected out in the `Select` clause):

```
var bunnies = db.Bunnies.Where(p => p.Color == "white")
                        .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                         {
                                            Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                                            Text = x.Name,
                                         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter in this easier way

```
ViewBag.RoomList = new SelectList(db.rooms.Where(p => p.hotel_id == 626191), "room_id", "title");
```